Error while Docker setup version is obsolete error during connect
I'm new to Docker in Sitecore. While Setting up the Docker Locally template and all things installed but when running  .\up.ps1 I'm facing the below error. Is there anyone facing the same issue please let me know.

PS C:\Workstation\DockerLearing\DockerLearning> .\up.ps1 Building containers...
time="2024-09-10T17:11:50+05:30" level=warning msg="C:\\Workstation\\DockerLearing\\DockerLearning\\run\\sitecore-xp}\\docker-compose.override.yml: `version` is obsolete"
error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect: Head "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/_ping": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot f ind the file specified. C:\Workstation\DockerLearing\DockerLearning\up.ps1: Container build failed, see errors above.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\up.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo
: Not Specified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException, up.ps1



Add more details here or add error in text for SEO

HI @Rahul, Please add your error in the text also, with an image for SEO purposes.

Added Error for reference

@Rahul Please confirm if the docker desktop is running on your host machine..

make sure your docker is open in Admin mode or you opened Windows PowerShell in admin mode as well.
Here are the steps to do it:
1. Open docker in  Admin mode.
2. Solr and Database services stopped.
3. Stopped the IIS
4. Switch to Windows containers.
5. opened Windows PowerShell in admin mode.
6. Run .\up.ps1
Hope it helps!

@Rahul you need to run your Windows PowerShell in administrator mode.
Here are the steps to do it:

Close your current PowerShell window
Right click the Windows PowerShell icon and select "Run as Administrator"
Navigate to your project folder in the PowerShell
Run .\up.ps1

Hope it helps!

You may need to verify the following things to make it resolve.

Run your Windows PowerShell in Admin mode and try again.
Open Docker Desktop and verify it's running.
Navigate to Windows taskbar.
Click on Docker icon.
Navigate to Switch to Windows Container. Like below.



Ensure that Hyper-V and Containers are checked

Refer to this blog for more docker-related errors.
https://buoctrenmay.com/2019/11/12/playing-around-with-the-set-up-of-sitecore-docker-images/
Hope this helps.

Thanks everyone for the tips it seems like my docker is not running at that time when I'm running .\up.ps1.
